# I'm trying to use dokuwiki parser engine in my website

Tags: php, wiki, dokuwiki

I'm developing some website and I want to put the dokuwiki engine as a text editor,
instead of some javascript-based wysiwyg engine.

I copied the code from the link below and tried with it.
http://www.dokuwiki.org/devel:parser#basic_invocation

The code supposed to compile the document "syntax.txt" into some xhtml document and echo the compiled document,
but what I get is just 'meh.'

If anyone have experience with this problem, please give me some hint.

Thanks.

p.s.

- I added `<?php` and `?>` to the code.
- I executed like $ php example.php
- I changed the path such as DOKU_INC, DOKU_DATA to appropriate path.

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself.

You can use [markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) instead of using dokuwiki engine.
It is actually the tool that stackoverflow uses.